# Initialize views on a Fragment causes app to crash

Tags: android, android-fragments, crash

I'm trying to create an EditText, a Button and a OnClickListener inside a Fragment to use with JavaMail but the app keeps crashing and if I remove this views the app works just fine but the JavaMail don't. I don't know if the problem is in the Fragment code or somewhere else. I'm new to programming so any help is welcome.

**FragmentOne.Java**

```
package info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;

import info.androidhive.materialtabs.R;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.SendMail;

public class OneFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    //Declaring EditText
    private EditText editTextMessage;

    //Send button
    private Button buttonSend;

        public OneFragment() {

        }  // Required empty public constructor

        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);}


    private void sendEmail() {
        //Getting content for email
        String email = "myemail@gmail.com";
        String subject = "mySubject";
        String message = editTextMessage.getText().toString().trim();

        //Creating SendMail object
        SendMail sm = new SendMail(this, email, subject, message);

        //Executing sendmail to send email
        sm.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        sendEmail();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
         editTextMessage = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);
         buttonSend = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);

        //Adding click listener
         buttonSend.setOnClickListener(this);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**fragment_one.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.OneFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                android:text="@string/chamado"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/preencha" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextMessage"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/descreva_o_problema"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/enviar"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Error**

```
    11-22 16:43:00.148 30210-30210/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
11-22 16:43:00.148 30210-30210/? E/Zygote: v2
11-22 16:43:00.158 30210-30210/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
11-22 16:43:03.198 30210-30210/info.androidhive.materialtabs E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: info.androidhive.materialtabs, PID: 30210
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.OneFragment.onCreateView(OneFragment.java:60)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
                                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:607)
                                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:674)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1835)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:725)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:616)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1835)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:725)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:616)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2881)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2237)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1537)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1180)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6558)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view is not inflated on `onCreate()` method of the fragment.
Initialize your widgets in an aproppiate lifecycle method such as `onCreateView`
Example:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(<your.custom.layout>, container, false);
    editTextMessage = rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);
    buttonSend = rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);

    //Adding click listener
    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(this)
    return rootView;
}
```

[Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) you can understand Fragment lifecycle.

Comment: Can you upload the stacktrace of the error you are getting?

Comment: Ok, can u update you code after applying my suggested changes? are you still calling getView()?

Comment: Yes I'm still calling getView()

Comment: As I suspected, do not call getView(). Use rootView for inflating your widgets as suggested in the answer.  The reason of this is because you are calling getView() in the same method that sets said view. So you are obiously getting a Nullpointer excepetion.

Comment: Check on the answer:   [rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);]

Comment: Thanks, that worked just fine! But now the app is crashing when I click on the button

Comment: Mmm that sound like a whole different problem. Ill gladly help you if you update the stack trace. Never the less if the answer solved the initial question I would appreciate if you mark it as correct :)

Comment: For sure, thanks! So I'll make another question for this problem.